# How to use references and pointers in c++ classes?

Tags: class, pointers, reference

i have the following problem: I am using an existing class which creates an object called server_t.
Another function expects *server_t as an argument.

I wanted to shrink the code and added a class which has following members:

```
#ifndef _PMCLASS
#define _PMCLASS

#include "pmlib.h"

class pmServer{

private:

     server_t server ;
     counter_t counter;
     line_t lines;
     server_t * server2;
     int set, frequency, aggregate ;

public:

    pmServer();
    pmServer(int set, int frequency, int aggregate);
    ~pmServer();

    void setSet(int s);
    void setFrequency(int f);
    void setAggregate(int a);

    int getSet(void);
    int getFrequency(void);
    int getAggregate(void);

    server_t* getServerT(void);
    counter_t* getCounterT(void);
    line_t* getLineT(void);

    server_t* getZeiger(void);
};
#endif
```

then i created the constructors:

```
#include "pmClass.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void pmServer::setSet(int s){
this->set = s;
}

void pmServer::setFrequency(int f){
this->frequency = f;
}

void pmServer::setAggregate(int a){
this->aggregate = a;
}

int pmServer::getSet(void){
return set;
}

int pmServer::getFrequency(void){
return frequency;
}

int pmServer::getAggregate(void){
return aggregate;
}

 server_t* pmServer::getPointer(){
 return &server;    
}
pmServer::pmServer(){
set = -1;
frequency = 0;
aggregate = 1;
```

}

then i tried to create an object ->worked, but then i wanted to use the pm_set_server(...)
it wants following arguments: int pm_set_server( char *ip, int port, server_t *pm_server)

```
void run() {
 build_initial_mesh();
    // Construct / read in the initial mesh.
pmServer server1; 
pm_set_server("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 6526,server1.getPointer); //its a correct ip address , no panic :)
```

i got that:

error: argument of type 'server_t*' (pmServer::)() does not match 'server_t*'

but this worked without any problems:

```
void run() {
    // Construct / read in the initial mesh.
    //pmServer server1;
    server_t test;
    pm_set_server("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 6526,&test);

    build_initial_mesh();
```

The thing is, i didn't want to create everytime new ojects and wanted to do that in the constructor...Does somebody have any idea?

thanks.

greetings Thomas

Comment: What is the point of `server` and `server2`? They don't seem to be used.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, function calls need brackets*:

```
pm_set_server("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 6526,server1.getPointer());
```

*exceptions apply, for operators.